# How to apply pointer-events to simple-table using rowspan in Vue.js?

Tags: css, typescript, vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

I made the table using v-simple-table in Vuetify.js framework as Nuxt.js.
When I click on "XXX Inc.", I want the table cells for HR, business, HR,sales and business to all be marked out.
But now only first row pointed like following.

[image: img]

My code is below.
Could anyone advise me?

```
    <template>
  <v-simple-table dense>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>company</th>
        <th>division</th>
        <th>section</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">XX Inc.</td>
        <td>H/R</td>
        <td>H/R</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">business</td>
        <td>sales</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>marketing</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </v-simple-table>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'

@Component({})
export default class extends Vue {}
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.v-data-table--dense > .v-data-table__wrapper > table > tbody > tr > td {
  border-bottom: thin solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: So when you click on "XXX inc", you want the table cells for HR, business, HR, sales and business to all be marked out? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. That's right. I'm sorry  I couldn't explain it well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group your "rows" with `<tbody>` and add the css:

```
tbody:hover tr {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

See [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-forked-3jpy5?file=/src/layout.vue:1188-1234) forked from vuetify playground.

Comment: Sir.....It's like magic for me!!! I was really surprised and really appreciate it!! I have to study about css.....